# How can I change the length of the webkit-scrollbar-thumb?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a fancy scrollbar, but have the problem that I do not like the length. Can you somehow change that? So with `height: x;` it does not work.

**If someone marks this question as a duplicate, then let me know in advance, because I searched for 10 minutes.**

Answer (score 2):

```
/* Resize / 10px 10px suggested  */
::-webkit-scrollbar{
  width:10px; /* for vertical scrollbar */
  height:10px /* for horizontal scrollbar */
}

/* up down arrows . */
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:start:decrement,
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:end:increment{
  display:none;
}

/* Background */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece{
  background-color:#e6e6e6
}

/* hold piece */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
  -webkit-border-radius:4px;
  background:#444;
}
```

Comment: Also lets keep in mind that `height` only affects the horizontal scrollbar, and `width` only the vertical scrollbar

Comment: Oh sorry my fault, i mean the length of the "thumb". [here](https://imgur.com/a/NuAuXRy)

Comment: it's height not changeable.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* -------------------------------- 
Scroll Bar style
-------------------------------- */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background: white;
  width: 4px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #666;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
}

::selection {
  background-color: white;
  color: #111;
}

::-moz-selection {
  background-color: white;
  color: #111;
}
```